# How to set list object c#

Tags: c#, linq

i'm using two list as methods paremeters on a controller but right now i'm getting a problem... Per example, i have the first list with three objects and the second list with three objects too. Right know i just want to get per each object from the first list the corresponding object from the second list.. like [0]-[0];[1]-[1];[2]-[2]...

I use two foreach to iterate each list but the problem cames when after i go to the second object from Turno list because after that when i start the iteration of DocenteId List the iteration starts at the [0] object but in the reality i don't want the first object of DocenteId list again but the second...

The if clause that i have is just because i cannot repeat the TurnoId value that cames with the Turno list object... The real thing happens when the DocenteId list cames with same values like object[0]-1;object[1]-1;object[1]-2; I want this to happen but i just want to get three values as result on the turnodocente List so here is the problem i just can switch the Turno object but not the DocenteId object... What happens with my method right now is that the result came with three values but foreach Turno object i get always the first object value for DocenteId list and i don't want that....

Exists some way to get this?

I will apreciate your help...

**Controller method**

```
foreach (var item in Turno)
{
    foreach (var ite in DocenteId)
    {
        if (!turnodocente.Any(x =>x.TurnoId == item.TurnoId))
        {
            turnodocente.Add(new TurnoDocente
            {
                TurnoId = item.TurnoId,
                DocenteId = ite
            });                             
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if i fully understand your problem but, if both lists have the same number of objects, i think the solution could be like:

```
for(int i=0; i<Turno.Count(); i++)
{
    turnodocente.Add(new TurnoDocente
        {
            TurnoId = Turno[i],
            DocenteId = DocenteId[i]
        });  
}
```

Let me know if it helps you.

EDIT: I just tought it might be good to explain. When you use foreach in another foreach, the iteration of indexes looks like this:
0 - 0, 0 - 1, 0 - 2... 1 - 0, 1 - 1, 1 - 2... etc so basicaly there is a * a iterations. What you need is just one iteration through both lists, so "for" loop is a good option because you will get objects from both lists that are at the same index. I hope it's clrear :)

Comment: Yeah man. It works very well. It's some like this that i need

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have the same number of objects in both lists;

```
   var Turno = new List<int>() {1000, 2000, 3000};
        var DocenteId = new List<int> {5000, 6000, 7000};

        var turnodocente = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < Turno.Count; i++)
        {
            if (turnodocente.All(x => x.Key != Turno[i]))
            {
                turnodocente.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(Turno[i], DocenteId[i]));
                Console.WriteLine(turnodocente[i].Key +" " + turnodocente[i].Value);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might need [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Zip__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Func___0___1___2__)

```
List<int> turno = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3};
List<string> docenteId = new List<string> {"foo", "bar", "doe"};

IEnumerable<TurnoDocente> turnodocente = turno.Zip(docenteId, (x, y) => new TurnoDocente() {TurnoId = x, DocenteId = y} );
```